# Detecting 3 continuous odd or even number in an array

Tags: java, if-statement

While I was practicing **Java** Problems on coding bat I came across the following problem statement:-

Problem:-

Given an array of integers, return true if the array contains either 3 even or 3 odd values all next to each other.

Example:-

```
modThree([2, 1, 3, 5]) → true
modThree([2, 1, 2, 5]) → false
modThree([2, 4, 2, 5]) → true
```

My Solution:-

```
public boolean modThree(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0; i<nums.length-2; i++){
    if((nums[i] % 2 == 0 && nums[i+1] % 2 == 0 && nums[i+2] % 2 == 0) || (nums[i] % 2 == 1 && nums[i+1] % 2 == 1 && nums[i+2] % 2 == 1)){
      return true;
    }
  }
    return false;
}
```

Though my solution works, my solution looks a bit long(especially the if statement condition). So, I am looking for a solution with fewer lines of code. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Fewer lines of code? One `for` loop, one `if` statement, and two `return` statements. How could you possibly shorten that?

Comment: OP is looking for shorter IF statement may be

Comment: *FYI:* Don't use invalid Java syntax in the question, when Java has perfectly valid syntax for the purpose, i.e. use **varargs**: Method declaration `public boolean modThree(int... nums)` allows call to be `modThree(2, 1, 3, 5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three `modulo` values must be equal, not necessarily 0 or 1 (although `% 2` makes 0 and 1 the single possible results). Therefore, you can replace the `if` statement with:

```
if(nums[i]%2 == nums[i+1]%2 && nums[i]%2 == nums[i+2]%2) {
    ...
}
```